# one table or different tables for different transactions?

Tags: mysql, database-design

considering an app for online consulation and managing patients. there are 3 types of transactions. 1- users/doctors can withdraw, or deposit money in their wallet 2-users can pay for online consulations . 3- doctors can pay for their account (account has different plans).

now I want to design a transaction table for saving details after payment. should I have the same table for all of these and make columns like transaction_type and transaction_user_type to understand who has paid (the doctor or user) and understand what transaction it is (for consulation , wallet, or account)? or should I have different tables for these?

Comment: All described payment types are the same entity - so one transactions table is reasonable. The type of the transaction is a property of this entity only.

Comment: @Akina thanks. how about diffrent users ? one coulmn for distingushing if doctor or user has paid?

Comment: *how about diffrent users ?* You'd decide this self. I'd prefer to consider that both doctor and user are the same people/customer entity. So I'd store them in one table. But I'd create two separate tables (for doctors and for users) which refers to customers table and stores the data specific for separate customer type.

Comment: @Akina no i have different entities because there are different attributes.

Comment: The doctor can be sometimes a patient, is it? will you create two separate records for the same man?

Comment: @Akina how about too much null attributes in user table ? and maybe doctor wants to use site as unknown patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have one transaction table.  It will make it so much easier to do financial reports and stats.

Don't forget to have fields to process

- refunds
- advance payments
- partial payments
- afterpay type support (there are ones that pay right away, and others that pay periodically)

---

I handle refunds by storing negative quantities instead of positive.  Thing to watch out for, you can make the qty and total price negative, but not the unit price.  Otherwise, two negatives multiplied together give a positive.
On one project, I put in a field (a flag) to indicate a refund.  It just helped in reports to distinguish refunds for stats.

Comment: thanks, how do you handle refunds?

Comment: and do you agree with transaction_user_type

Comment: Yes, you need the transaction type, user_type and maybe a few more fields if you want to support the above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it from OOP/OOD perspective. Some attributes will be common for all transaction types and some attributes will be specific.

As a result, you could do a mixed approach:

- One table with the common attributes.
- Separate tables for each transaction type for the specific attributes.
- Each specific table should have a reference to the central table.

However, don't overdo OOP things in the database. E.g. avoid many levels of inheritance. This hybrid approach keeps things still relatively simple, while allowing you to easily scale for different transaction types with few drawbacks.

As for performance - do not worry. There are ways to avoid locking problems. We have many TB-size databases using this approach.